# Why does my Linear SVM on SIFT Features converge, but not a non-Linear SVM or a Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

I have two distinct texture classes of 1000 images each with varying amounts of blur and noise (but with a reasonable threshold on both so that even if both are at their highest levels the class of the image is reasonably discernible to the human eye). I successfully trained a Linear Support Vector Machine on the classification task, but moving to a non-linear SVM (in sci-kit learn) or a convolutional neural network both yield no success. More specifically, they are all stuck predicting everything as the same class.

Training the CNN has the same effect: accuracy is consistently stuck at 50%, despite my multiple initializations with different optimization and loss functions. For the sake of the question, I'll provide an example of each class:

[image]
[image]

The class that the non-linear SVMs are favoring is the "striped" class.  Does anyone have an idea why this might be occurring?